# Bluetooth support in Android on Beaglebone

Tags: android, bluetooth, beagleboneblack

I am cutting my teeth on Android this week and I have a Beaglebone Black running an Android JB 4.2.2, linux kernel 3.2 image from TI with a Broadcomm BCM20702 usb bluetooth dongle attached.

The dongle works alright in Angstrom but I am sufficiently neophyte as to not recognise if the support is there in Jelly bean. 
I begun testing with the following code:

```
private BluetoothAdapter BA;
BA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
Intent turnOn = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
startActivityForResult(turnOn, 0);
```

I get my BA, i get my turnOn intent but when I start the intent I get the allow permissions dialogs then the "Turning Bluetooth on..." modal indication which never clears.
The application threads are all running in the debugger but the UI looses focus and is unresponsive.

What can I do to debug the situation ?
How do I determine whether the dongle really is supported in this kernel or enable support if not ?
What provisions are in the Android UI for bluetooth connection/setup (I haven't seen any which may indicate a current lack of support)?

How can I debug the hung dialog "Turning Bluetooth on..." ?

Cheers much,
Chris